# Cant we create an Android AR app without using Sceneform?

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I am trying out AR development for the first time and whenever am trying to find some sample projects to follow almost all of the Google results show AR using ARCore and Sceneform.

Comment: Those are just libraries.  So yeah, you could do all the work they do and write your own from scratch.  Just expect it to take a ton of time, or to provide very limited functionality compared to using an existing framework.

Comment: @GabeSechan From what I read, google discontinued support for sceneform a long time ago. And replace the same with ARCore. I thought since ARCore was replacing sceneform, google might have improved on the same. Moreover, since the sceneform library was discontinued what if something breaks in a newer android version? We will have to wait until someone actually makes the changes in sceneform right?
Sharing my concerns or thoughts before starting actual work.

Comment: That's a totally different question that what you asked.  You asked if it was possible to create an AR app without using sceneform.  It is, you can write an AR project from absolute scratch, you just end up doing a lot of work.  Worrying about the risk of a library being abandoned, especially one from Google, is a legit concern.  But its not really on topic here, as it falls into opinion.  If you want advice on how to do it without a library that's a topic you can ask about, but you need to get down to specific questions. As is this is too vague.

Comment: Use Sceneform Maintained (https://github.com/SceneView/sceneform-android)
It's a continuation of Sceneform by open-source contributors. Otherwise, you can use ARCore and for rendering you can use OpenGL.

Comment: @MohamedGafar now we have two libraries right, sceneform-android and sceneview-android? one for java and the other for kotlin